# Cannot get Verbose/ full logging to work in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to log the output of my powershell script so as to remove failed image locations. My script (import.ps1) basically looks into a csv file with destination and source locations and does the copy. So far I get a blank log file.

This is what I have tried:

```
$(Import-Csv -Path E:\fileslist3.csv -ErrorAction Stop | foreach {
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $_.Destination))
{
    # Create directory if needed
    mkdir -Path $_.Destination -WhatIf
}
# Copy file
Copy-Item -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination
}
)*>&1 > c:\log.txt
```

Thank you

Comment: A statement `*>&1 > c:\log.txt` on a separate line should be throwing an error. Please show your actual code.

Comment: Sorry I just edited the code. It isn't on another line

Comment: What output do you expect? AFAICS the only output your code would produce are errors and `-WhatIf` messages (which would lead to other errors because with `-WhatIf` present a missing directory won't be created).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would look at this again